# What does "getting lazy at it." mean?

Tags: expressions

It was this situation that someone keeps going on about himself, like where's hes' been to, what are his extraordinary life events have been, all sorts of basically boring and dull stuffs.

In this situation, I heard someone say "Everyone else is getting lazy at it."

What does it mean?

Comment: More context is needed to interpret this. Without that, one cannot say just what was meant. I suspect it was an ironic comment which was not to be taken literally.

Comment: Are you sure you heard this from a native speaker? It looks to me like a non-native speaker's failure to correctly replicate *Everyone else is getting **tired of** it* (they're bored of listening to this bore). And or something to do with *everyone's eyes **glaze over*** (they cease to pay attention).

Comment: Oh right I think i got it wrong. I watched this clip (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=darbsQDKpsk&list=LLoQ3bUesEnCOLY3vvkOAoqw&index=2&t=0s) and made some modifications, based on what I understood they say in the video. At the beginning of the clip (at around 0:05), they say "they're getting lazy at it." I'm sorry for a confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An idiom you can use:

to be getting [x] at [something].

He is getting good **at lying.** 
He is getting good **at it**.  it=lying

They are getting lazy **at it**.
They are getting lazy **at playing tennis**.

to get [good, lazy, quick, etc.] is the first part of the idiom which means: to become good, lazy or quick

**at** should be followed by a verb phrase and that verb phrase, if the context is known, can become simply **it**.

- I think I am getting good at explaining these idioms.
- I think I am getting good at it.
- But I may soon get lazy at it. [explaining these idioms]

[The last examples are a joke used to make my point.]

Comment: Oh that was what it 'literally' means! Didn't know that. I thought there's any established idiom/expression like "getting lazy at sth" Thanks!

Comment: @Jin It is not just lazy. The adjective can be changed: **They are getting good at cooking**.  **They are getting bad at traveling.".

Comment: I get your point. So, in this situation that I described above, can I substitute 'lazy' with 'bored'? ;  Like "Everyone else is getting bored."

Comment: @Jin With *bored*, the preposition would need to be *by*: *I am getting bored **by** it*. However, to maintain the actual idiom (which that would not), it's possible (albeit a bit unusual) to say *I am getting **boring** at it.*